# Find measurement which fits corresponds to same variable at other locations

Tags: matlab

If I have wind speed measurements for 4 different locations within a geographical radius of approximately 400km for one year, is there a method for determining which wind speed measurement best fits all of the location i.e. does one of the locations have a similar wind speed to all other locations? Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could find the one that provides minimum e.g. quadratic loss from all the others:

```
speeds is an N-by-4 matrix, with N windspeed measurements for each location
%Loss will find the squared loss for location i. It subtracts column i from each column in speeds, and squares this difference (for column i, this will always be 0). Then average over all rows and the 3 non-zero columns.
loss = @(i)sum(mean((speeds - repmat(speeds(:, i), 1, 4)).^2)) ./ 3;
%Apply loss to each of the 4 locations, find the minimum.
[v i] = min(arrayfun(loss, 1:4));
```

The loss function takes the average squared difference between each windspeed and the speeds at all other locations. Then we use `arrayfun` to calculate this loss for each location.